# Read all html tables from tennis players activity page

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to read all html tables containing Federer's results from this website: http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/roger-federer/f324/player-activity
and store the data in one single data frame. One way I figured out was using the rvest package, but as you may notice, my code only works for a specific number of tournaments. Is there any way I can read all relevant tables with one command? Thank you for your help!

```
Url <- "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/roger-federer/f324/player-activity"
x<- list(length(4))
for (i in 1:4) {
    results <- Url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath=paste0("//table[@class='mega-table'][", i, "]")) %>%
    html_table()

    results <- results[[1]]
    x[[i]] <- resultados
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution above was close to being the final solution.  One downside of your code was having the read_html statement inside the for loop, this would greatly slow down the processing.  In the future read the page into a variable and then process the page node by node as necessary.

In this solution, I read the web page into the variable "page" and then extracted the table nodes where class = mega-table.  One there, the html_table command returned a list of the tables of interest.   The do.call looped a rbind the tables together.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/roger-federer/f324/player-activity"

page<- read_html(url)
tablenodes<-html_nodes(page, "table.mega-table")
tables<-html_table(tablenodes)
#numoftables<-length(tables)

df<-do.call(rbind, tables)
```